# How to avoid losing event on input after toggle visivility?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which should keep the focus, because of program requirements. While using the software the input might be hidden at some point but when showing up again it should recover the focus, but it doesn't. Still if you check the binded events on the input you can see it did not actually lost the event.

There's a simple jsfiddle showing this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/5puu261v/

```js
$('#barcode').focus()

$('#barcode').focusout(function(){
  $(this).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('#barcode').toggle()">Toggle input</button>
<input type="text" id="barcode" />
```

It would be appreciated if I could fix or avoid it without binding the event back again.

**Edit:**

The point is: Why does the input doesn't get focused, after being toggled, when clicking on any other element (as the button that makes it visible again)?

Comment: There is in fact a blur or focusout event when toggeling. Do you need it just to have focus again when it is visible again, or must it have focus even when invisible?

Comment: you need to add a ".focus() to your onclick button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5puu261v/1/)**.

You could add the `.focus()` to the click event so every time the button clicked the input will be focused, like :

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#barcode').toggle().focus();
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<button>Toggle input</button>
<input type="text" id="barcode" />
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#barcode').focus()

$('#barcode').focusout(function(){
    $(this).focus();
});

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#barcode').toggle().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle input</button>
<input type="text" id="barcode" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I already have a function to manage the input focus, my question is why does it stop working and how to avoid it.

Comment: You're welcome, when you click on the button the clicked element by default gain the focus that why the input lose the focus for the button, to avoid that you should give the focus back to the input after the click as shown in the post here.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method `focus` again at `onclick` event of button:

```js
$('#barcode').focus()

$('#barcode').focusout(function(){
  $(this).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('#barcode').toggle();$('#barcode').focus();">Toggle input</button>
<input type="text" id="barcode" />
```